# My date-time picker of Bootstrap-4 is not working on Internet Explorer? Is there any Date-Time picker which will work on Bootstrap 4.0?

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4, timepicker

Date-Time picker of Bootstrap-4 not working on Internet Explorer.
How can I do so?
I have used Bootstrap-4 for entire project.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issue. We used flatpickr instead. It works in all browsers, including IE 11. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatpickr